# display an image in php, sent from web service

Tags: php, web-services, blob

I am making a php page where I receive data from a webservice Adampiere, the problem arose when I get a picture that is in blob.

I tried converting the image with
$data= "\xffd8ffe000104a46494600010101006000600000ffdb004300080606070605080707070909080a0c140d0c0b0b0c1912130f141d1a1f1e1d1a1c1c20242e2720222c231c1c2837292c30313434341f27393d38323c2e333432ffdb00 ..." 
(this code not is base64)

echo img src = "data: image / jpg; base64'. base64_encode ($ data)."

but does not work, I added the **header ("Content-type: jpg")** and I just download the code.
Someone can help me?. Please :'(

Comment: Does the webservice's documentation tell you what the encoding of the inbound image is?  If it is already base64-encoded you can maybe just dump it into the SRC attribute of your tag without the base64_encode command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer to my question: I found her doing a couple of conversions. The $Data string is a string of byte (in hexadecimal). What I did was convert $data to ascii (hex to ASCII) and then this to base 64 and printable as a base64 image with this code:

echo ' ';

Answer (score 0):

You should do this...

If the result is named `$data`....like so...

```
$data ="\xffd8ffe000104a46494600010101006000600000ffdb004300080606070605080707070909080a0c140d0c0b0b0c1912130f141d1a1f1e1d1a1c1c20242e2720222c231c1c2837292c30313434341f27393d38323c2e333432ffdb00";
```

Then....

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo $data; ?> "/>
```

Comment: Hi KyleK, thanks, but the $data not is an a base64, not show the image :(

Comment: What is that encoded in then?  do you know? most webservices have docs that you can find that stuff out with...

Comment: Maybe its just that first character "\" that needs to be hacked off??

Comment: I'm trying to know what enconded is, but when I put your code,  the inspector element, shows: "data:image/jpg;blob" but de image not appear, I'm searching information about this, but, if you knows about this, please tell me

Comment: Can you paste your exact data....the whole entire string length....I can check ...also what is the webservice?

Comment: this is all the content of $data https://www.dropbox.com/s/gvmg5oljolfpuqg/blob.txt

Comment: the answer to my question:  I found her doing a couple of conversions. The  $Data string is a string of byte (in hexadecimal). What I did was convert $data to ascii (hex to ASCII) and then this to base 64 and printable as a base64 image with this code:
echo ' <img src="data:image/png;base64,'. $data.'" />';